# Is it possible to BehaviorSubject reset my useState value?

Tags: rxjs

**Problem**: Whenever I click 't' key my theme changed as I expected. But for some reason this cause isModalVisible state reset. This cause one problem - When I have my modal open and click t - the modal disapear. I don't know why. Maybe BehaviorSubject cause the problem? Additionally, if I create another useState for test, which initial value is string 'AAA', and on open modal I set this state to string 'BBB'. Then I click 't' to change theme this test useState back to beginning value 'AAA'

My code looks like this:

```js
const Component1 = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useRecoilState(selectedModeState);

  const { switcher, status } = useThemeSwitcher();

  const toggleMode = (newTheme: MODE_TYPE) => {
    theme$.next({ theme: newTheme });
    localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const mode_sub = theme$.subscribe(({ theme }) => {
      switcher({ theme: theme });
      setMode(theme);
    });

    return () => {
      mode_sub.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return <Component2 toggleMode={toggleMode} currentMode={mode} />
}
```

```js
const Component2 = ({toggleMode, currentMode}) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(currentMode);
  const [savedTheme, setSavedTheme] = useRecoilState(selectedThemeState);

  const getTheme = mode === MODE_TYPE.LIGHT ? MODE_TYPE.DARK : MODE_TYPE.LIGHT;

  const themeListener = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 't':
        setMode(getTheme);
        toggleMode(getTheme);
        break;
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', themeListener);
    document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', savedTheme);
    localStorage.setItem('color', savedTheme);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', themeListener);
    };
  }, [savedTheme]);

  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

return (

<Modal isModalVisible={isModalVisible} setIsModalVisible={setIsModalVisible} />
)
}
```

UTILS:

```js
export const selectedModeState = atom<MODE_TYPE>({
  key: 'selectedThemeState',
  default: (localStorage.getItem('theme') as MODE_TYPE) || MODE_TYPE.LIGHT,
});

export const selectedThemeState = atom<string>({
  key: 'selectedColorState',
  default: (localStorage.getItem('color') as string) || 'blue',
});


export const theme$ = new BehaviorSubject({
  theme: (localStorage.getItem('theme') as THEME_TYPE) || THEME_TYPE.LIGHT,
});
```

I would like the theme change not to set visibleModal to false which causes the modal to close